# Ajax loaded page, pass POST data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

I have all my webpages loaded with ajax, I'm not sure how to include POST data from the loaded page. The goal is to have a registration form and post that data to another php file and have it processed there.

ajaxloader.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    }); 

    setInterval("checkURL()",250);
    loadPage('#Home');
});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#','');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

load_page.php

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];

if(file_exists($page.'.php'))
echo include($page.'.php');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could expand a bit more on what you are attempting to do and what it is not doing now?

Comment: You can't echo an include bro, you need `ob_start()`

Answer (score 0):

So your load_page.php woudl look like

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = $_POST['page'];
ob_start();

if(file_exists($page.'.php'))
include($page.'.php');
else echo 'There is no such page!';

$content = ob_get_clean();
echo $content;
```

This should do the job. HOWEVER, you can't just pass the whole website like that, you need to base64_encode() it make sure everything is ok. And then take a look at this
http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode/

Comment: My POST variables are still not being passed, do I need to do the base64_encode() to get those passed as well?